# Reading Data in Packages of Imported Packages

Tags: r, import, namespaces

The R-Commander GUI has the functionality of finding packages which have data in them after which they can be loaded in.

[image: Reading in Data in R Commander]

(Image of reading in data in R Commander https://i.stack.imgur.com/3upZ7.png)

The way this works is that R-Commander uses the `.packages()` command to find the *attached* packages. These are the packages which will appear in the first list in the image above.

So if you are making a plug-in for R-Commander and are using the Depends option in the description file, these packages will also appear in this list if they have got data in them.

The problem begins when you start using the Imports option in the description file instead of Depends. 
The problem does not lie in loading in the data. Even when using Imports instead of Depends, the following code still works. (Which will be the code executed when pressing the OK button)

```
data("nameofdata",package="nameofpackage")
```

However the package will not appear anymore in the list on the left in the image because it is not returned by `.packages()` (Because now the package is *loaded*, not *attached*.)

Now, my question:

1. I know I could use the `attachNamespace()` command to get my imported package back in this "attached packages vector" again. But am I not simply doing a Depends again, but in a more complicated way? Or is this still different from only using a normal Depends?
2. Is there any other way of getting around this problem? Is there another way of finding the *loaded* packages?

Comment: This is your third question on the same topic.  All your troubles are caused by using `Imports` rather than `Depends`.  Why are you switching code that works for code that doesn't work?  You are identifying the fundamental difference between these two options, and it seems you should stick with `Depends`.

Comment: (The first topic I was able to resolve and was luckily not related to this switch).
And yes you are correct. Currently my problems are being caused by this switch. The plug-in which is being developed is basically a platform in which a lot of R-packages for biclustering will be implemented. At the moment the plug-in is already depending on 8 different packages. The reasoning behind the switch to `Imports` is to hopefully decrease the initial loading time of the package and also avoid some problems of same-named functions in some of these packages.

Comment: Also, I suggest you remove references to RCommander.  Your problem has nothing to do with RCommander, and everything to do with NAMESPACE issues.  By tagging it incorrectly, you mnay not attract the attention you really need. Fix this in the title, too.

Comment: AFAIK, using Imports rather than Depends will not reduce loading time.  Resolving name conflicts is a good reason for using Imports.    However, I don't think it's easy to export a function defined in one of your imported packages.  Good luck.